# Clear cell content when another cell is entered

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Hi I'm very new to the google scripts, and would like to ask for your help.

In my spreadsheet, I need a script to clear data in cells I & J when a date is entered in cell H?

I.e. if a date is entered into H5, then clear all data in I5 & J5, or if a date is entered in H7 then clear all data in I7 & J7, etc.

Many Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the following section of the documentation [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#clearContent()).

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("month test"); // don't forget to change by your sheet name
  var statusValues = sheet.getRange("H:H").getValues();
  for (var row in statusValues) {
    try{
      if(statusValues[row][0]!="" && typeof statusValues[row][0]=="object"){
        var num = parseInt(row) + 1;
        sheet.getRange(num, 9,1,2).setValue("");
      }
    }
    catch(err){
      Logger.log("didn't worked line: "+row+" --- "+err)}
  }
};
```